# BottomNavigationView looks very bad

Tags: android, android-theme, android-bottomnav, android-bottom-nav-view

I'm using android support library BottomNavigationView , it looks very bad in some versions of android .

this is my code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#fff"
    app:theme="@style/mydrawer"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_items" />

in styles : 
 <style name="mydrawer">
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    </style>
```

it looks good in my phone with android 6 but it look very bad on most of the phones , like this:

[image]

as you can see, the text size in enormous

how can I fix this ?

Comment: change textsize using dimensions .... then they will get the appropriate textsize according to screen sizes.

Comment: @Umair thanks for reply but how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You specify one text size value for all devices:

```
 <style name="mydrawer">
     <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
 </style>
```

Instead of 14sp , you should specify value from dimens

```
 <style name="mydrawer">
     <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/bottom_bar_item_text_size</item>
 </style>
```

Create dimens.xml files for different screen sizes. You should create dimens.xml file for each screen size :

- normal
- large
- xlarge
- there are more of those, but those 3 are most common.

```html
<dimen name="bottom_bar_item_text_size">14sp</dimen>
```

Your dimens.xml files will look like that :

[image]

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bottom Navigation ViewEx for more customization and better appearence , usage is similar to that of normal view

[check out the github](https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx)